# How to attach instances to AWS autoscale when creating autoscale group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

Currently I have two instances running under elb. If I create an autoscale group with min size 2 with this elb, it spawns two more instances and puts it under elb.

But I only want the instances come up on scale out condition not on creation of the group.

Answer (score 0):

The min. instances in the autoscale group will be launched at creation.  If you only want 2 instances and then 2 more when scaling, you must setup your original 2 instances in the autoscale group initially otherwise the autoscale group has no knowledge of your (already) existing 2 instances.

What I do is to create my desired instance.  Snapshot it.  Terminate it, then relaunch in an autoscale group via the min parameter.  I then set the conditions for the extra instances to be launched when conditions are met, like CPU usage or any other attributed in cloudwatch.